# What is the error reported for AH01757, "generating secret for digest authentication ..."?

Tags: apache-http-server, error-logging

I'm working through our web server's error log for an Open Source project. I see repeated entries for:

```
$ cat /var/log/httpd/error_log-20160522 | grep "digest"     
[Mon May 16 08:11:29.004792 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 20628] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 19 09:45:18.519977 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 12588] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 19 09:47:10.331913 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 128] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 19 14:59:26.211893 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 7102] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
...
```

The configuration file is `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. `LogLevel` is set to `LogLevel warn`. `ErrorLog` is set to `"logs/error_log"`.

What, exactly, is the error Apache is reporting? How do I fix it?

---

```
$ hostnamectl
  ...
    Virtualization: openvz
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-042stab113.17
      Architecture: x86-64

$ apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   May 12 2016 10:27:23
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore it, it's informational and reporting no error. It has already been dropped to DEBUG level in 2.5.x (trunk) which means you will not see it in a later release.

I will see about getting the change in log level backported to 2.4.x

Comment: This made it into 2.4.25