# Apache error file and file size

Tags: mamp

I use MAMP to run php local. Inside there is the file apache_error.log that grows fast every time that I open or close Mamp:
aplications/mamp/logs/apache_error.log

If I delete apache_error.log and open and close again Mamp it gives me that errors:

```
[Wed Jul 19 16:25:13 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 19 16:25:13 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jul 19 16:25:13 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 5576)
[Wed Jul 19 16:25:13 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12 PHP/7.0.10 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2h DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 19 16:25:43 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

And each time that file grows 509 bytes

I could find that I could ignore the first error:
[What is the error reported for AH01757, "generating secret for digest authentication ..."?](https://superuser.com/questions/1081758/what-is-the-error-reported-for-ah01757-generating-secret-for-digest-authentica)

I could not find any information about the other errors and I do not understand what is about.

Comment: If you check the tag it is `[notice]` = INFO, not error

Comment: @Romeo Ninov do you mean I can ignore all that errors?

Comment: Met me say it again: those are not errors. And yes, you can ignore them